R ggplot boxplot: add compact letter display (CLD) along with facet wrap and aes(colour), 3-way factorial design
I hope this is not a replicated question, I've roamed this website without finding an exact answer to my doubts.
I've performed a a 3-ways factorial experiment (3 independent, categorical variables) which, for confidentiality, will be transformed into "banana yumminess VS watering liquid * day of ripening * type of banana tree".
Yumminess is continuous, the response variable. Type has 2 levels, watering is a treatment with 6 levels, and all bananas were tested in each of the sampling day, therefore days of ripening was converted from integer to 9 levels.
Asterisk is used to indicate multiplicative interaction between IVs, as usual in R, because I'm interested in the effect of each IV on yumminess, but also if their interaction changes with time: we suppose that, at the end of our study period, all bananas will taste poorly, and eastern bananas will be the first to do so.
--By the way, if any of you is aware of a 3-way, non parametric factorial test, I'm really looking for it. For the moment I'm doing Kruskal Wallis tests for each variable, which is great. I'm aware that I can fit a model, but I'm really looking for something very, very simple to report to my colleagues. ARTAnova was promising, but as far as I understood, it "slices" the dataset by one of the variables, while I'm interested in all three IVs, all considered together--
I've successfully created the plot of my dreams (behold!) Banana boxplot now in R with ggplot2, thanks to multiple comments in this website.
It's perfect as it is, including the "blank" boxplot in the "Tea x Eastern" treatment (it was not applied, and I want to show that).
I am aware that, in aes(), the x is TYPE: it was the solution I found to have boxplots grouped by type (if x = TREATMENT, I'm getting boxplots paired by treatment, i.e. the boxplot "treatment water x eastern" next to "water x western", and so on).
What I am now trying to achieve is only to display CLD on the top of each single tiny boxplot Banana boxplot with handmade CLD.
I was able to do so for 1-way boxplots (not shown), and I tried to cycle ggplot inside a for cycle, but my little experience with ggplot and R in general is getting in my way.
I assume it would be possible to store all CLD values in a vector sequentially, and then superimpose the values to the layer obtained, but I really don't know how to do this--and maybe there's a more elegant/automatic way.
I tried geom_tukey from ggtukey, but it didn't work, as I only get 1 letter per "set" of 5/6 boxplots (18 letters in total).
I guess that the difficulty arises because of the use of both facet_wrap, and colour = TREATMENT together (which allows me to include all 3 factors in the figure).
Here the code used:
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mwe_boxplot, aes(x = TYPE, y = RESPONSE, colour = TREATMENT)) +
  geom_boxplot(na.rm = F) +
  facet_wrap(~ DAY)+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(nrow = 1)) +
  ggtitle("Banana yumminess by type, treatment and day of ripening")+
  xlab("Type of banana tree") +
  ylab("Response (yumminess)") +
  labs(colour = 'Main treatment (fertiliser)') +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c('Eastern', 'Western')) +
  theme_pubclean(base_size = 12) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(10, 50))

Here the structure of my dataset, in full (thanks @Edward for your comment).
> dput(mwe_boxplot)
structure(list(TREATMENT = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), levels = c("Water", "Beer", "Soda", 
"Wine", "Tea", "Coffee"), class = "factor"), TYPE = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("Eastern", 
"Western"), class = "factor"), DAY = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), levels = c("328", "353", 
"396", "458", "497", "586", "625", "692", "767"), class = "factor"), 
    YUMMINESS = c(24, 26.3, 27.6, 31.8, 32.4, 26.5, 30.5, 30.6, 
    31.3, 32.3, 33.3, 41.1, 24.1, 27.2, 28.1, 28.2, 31.5, 32, 
    32.5, 33, 33.6, 34.8, 40.1, 23.3, 23.8, 23.8, 24.9, 25.2, 
    25.2, 25.8, 26, 29.1, 29.4, 23.8, 31.8, 32.5, 34.3, 35.5, 
    37.6, 24.4, 24.9, 25.3, 26.3, 27.4, 28, 28.1, 28.4, 30.1, 
    30.7, 31.5, 21.1, 21.2, 21.6, 21.7, 21.8, 21.9, 22, 22, 22.2, 
    22.3, 22.3, 23.2, 24.2, 18.7, 18.8, 20, 22.9, 23, 23.2, 23.4, 
    15.1, 16.4, 16.6, 16.9, 18, 18.2, 18.7, 21.3, 22.1, 22.4, 
    24.6, 23.3, 23.5, 24.4, 24.8, 30.3, 33.4, 34.1, 35.2, 22.5, 
    22.8, 23.6, 24.3, 25.2, 27.8, 28.5, 28.7, 31, 32.1, 32.1, 
    24.9, 26.2, 28, 28, 28, 29, 31.8, 33, 25.1, 26.8, 29.3, 30.6, 
    32.8, 34.2, 34.6, 23, 23.5, 24, 24.4, 24.6, 28.2, 31.2, 33.5, 
    23.6, 24.3, 24.6, 25.5, 26.4, 28.1, 28.2, 24.9, 24.9, 27.1, 
    30, 35.6, 15.3, 16.1, 16.4, 18.6, 18.7, 19.5, 19.8, 20.9, 
    20.8, 20.9, 21.6, 23.5, 25.4, 24, 24.7, 24.8, 27, 27.2, 28.5, 
    30.2, 30.3, 31.9, 32.3, 32.3, 32.4, 25.9, 26.1, 27.1, 29.2, 
    30, 30, 33.3, 33.5, 35, 36.6, 39.3, 39.6, 27.1, 27.3, 31.3, 
    36, 37.9, 38.8, 39.2, 40.1, 42.7, 23.2, 23.7, 23.8, 24.1, 
    24.6, 25, 25.3, 25.6, 25.9, 25.9, 26.2, 26.6, 28, 26.8, 27.5, 
    30.1, 30.5, 30.7, 34.7, 35.8, 37.5, 43.1, 44.9, 24.2, 26.7, 
    27.3, 28.9, 30, 31.9, 33, 33.4, 34.9, 36.2, 21.5, 21.8, 21.9, 
    22.1, 22.2, 22.3, 22.7, 22.7, 22.9, 22.9, 23.9, 18.3, 19.7, 
    21.6, 22.5, 23.8, 24.6, 25, 25.6, 26.8, 27.2, 14.7, 15, 15, 
    17.7, 18.7, 19, 20.2, 22.7, 26.4, 22.5, 22.8, 23.8, 23.9, 
    25.7, 33.8, 36.2, 22.1, 23.5, 23.8, 26.8, 29.5, 29.6, 30.4, 
    33.5, 33.7, 38.4, 24.6, 26.3, 27.3, 27.6, 27.7, 29.4, 29.7, 
    26.4, 30.7, 31.5, 23, 24, 24.3, 24.6, 27.7, 30.9, 32.1, 37, 
    21.2, 22, 22.3, 23.1, 23.3, 25.8, 29, 22.2, 24.7, 25, 26.9, 
    30.3, 33.2, 16.3, 16.7, 17, 17.8, 18.2, 19, 20.5, 20.7, 20.8, 
    21, 23.1, 18.9, 21.3, 24.4, 25.3, 23.9, 24.1, 24.3, 24.3, 
    24.5, 25, 25.8, 26.4, 30.4, 23.8, 24, 24.1, 24.6, 25.2, 25.3, 
    25.3, 25.6, 26.1, 26.4, 27.1, 28.3, 28.3, 33, 25.1, 25.2, 
    25.9, 26.4, 27, 27.2, 28.1, 28.5, 29.1, 29.4, 30, 30.4, 31.5, 
    36.2, 24.3, 24.8, 25.7, 26.3, 26.4, 25.9, 26, 26.1, 27.3, 
    28.3, 29.5, 30, 37.4, 22.7, 23.5, 24.1, 24.1, 25.1, 26.4, 
    27.7, 21.3, 21.6, 21.9, 22.1, 22.2, 22.3, 22.4, 23, 23.6, 
    19.2, 19.6, 19.7, 20.1, 20.5, 20.6, 21, 21, 21.1, 21.3, 22.4, 
    22.9, 13.8, 16.3, 16.9, 17, 18, 18.1, 18.2, 18.5, 18.7, 19.5, 
    20.9, 21.2, 22.6, 22.7, 22.8, 22.8, 25.4, 30.8, 41.5, 21.8, 
    22, 22, 30.3, 23.5, 24.7, 24.9, 25.3, 26, 27, 28.9, 24.4, 
    26, 26, 28, 29, 30.2, 31.4, 22.3, 22.4, 23, 24, 26.3, 26.5, 
    29, 29.3, 20.3, 22.4, 22.9, 23, 23.3, 23.4, 23.7, 23.8, 22.5, 
    24, 26.7, 27.5, 16, 16.5, 17.8, 18.6, 18.9, 18.9, 20.4, 20.6, 
    21.9, 17.5, 18.4, 19.9, 23.5, 23.8, 22.9, 23.7, 23.7, 24.3, 
    24.3, 24.6, 24.8, 25, 25.3, 25.4, 25.4, 26, 23.3, 24.1, 24.2, 
    25.3, 25.4, 25.6, 26, 28.7, 23.7, 25, 25.3, 26, 26.1, 26.3, 
    26.5, 26.9, 27.2, 27.5, 30.3, 22.8, 23, 23.2, 23.5, 24.1, 
    24.3, 25.3, 25, 25.5, 26.1, 27.2, 27.7, 28, 28.3, 28.3, 28.5, 
    32.8, 32.8, 21.8, 22.1, 23, 23, 23.1, 23.2, 24.1, 24.2, 24.7, 
    25.6, 25.8, 26.9, 21.4, 21.6, 21.7, 21.8, 22.3, 22.3, 22.5, 
    22.5, 23.7, 23.8, 23.9, 19.4, 19.9, 20, 20.6, 20.7, 20.8, 
    21.6, 14.9, 17.8, 18.4, 18.7, 19, 20, 20.5, 21.9, 22.7, 23.6, 
    23.6, 25.4, 26.5, 27.5, 28.6, 33.1, 21.9, 21.9, 22.7, 25.5, 
    26.4, 27.2, 28.1, 30.2, 32, 25.3, 25.6, 25.8, 26.2, 26.6, 
    27.6, 29.5, 23.5, 25.8, 26.3, 28.2, 28.6, 28.9, 29.6, 22.5, 
    22.9, 23.3, 23.5, 24.1, 26.7, 27.1, 28.5, 29.1, 20.9, 21.5, 
    24, 24.7, 26.3, 22.4, 22.4, 23, 23, 24.1, 24.6, 25.3, 29.7, 
    16.5, 16.6, 18.5, 18.7, 19, 19, 19.5, 18.3, 18.4, 20.2, 21, 
    23.2, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 
    23.2, 27.4, 21.7, 21.8, 22.9, 23, 23.3, 27, 34.2, 25.9, 26, 
    26, 26.9, 28.4, 29, 31.7, 23.3, 24.3, 24.8, 25.6, 25.7, 27.2, 
    30.4, 31.2, 22.2, 23.2, 23.6, 26.5, 28.8, 30.3, 22.2, 22.8, 
    23.4, 23.5, 23.8, 25.2, 26.1, 22.6, 23.1, 23.3, 24, 26, 26.3, 
    26.5, 27.4, 16.5, 16.7, 17.9, 18.2, 19, 19.3, 20, 20.2, 20.3, 
    20.5, 17.9, 18.8, 19.3, 23, 23.9, 24.8, 24.9, 25.3, 25.7, 
    27.1, 27.7, 29.3, 24.4, 24.5, 25.2, 25.3, 25.5, 26.5, 27.1, 
    27.8, 30.3, 31.5, 31.6, 33.6, 35.7, 24.6, 25.3, 25.8, 30.4, 
    30.9, 33.4, 35.6, 38.5, 39.7, 42.5, 22.6, 24.6, 24.8, 25, 
    27, 27.3, 27.6, 24.3, 29.9, 30.4, 33.2, 33.4, 34, 36, 22.8, 
    25.1, 25.5, 26.9, 26.9, 27.1, 27.2, 27.5, 32.1, 20.9, 21, 
    21.5, 21.6, 21.6, 21.7, 22.3, 22.4, 23.5, 24.6, 18, 18.9, 
    20.2, 21.3, 22.1, 23, 24.6, 25.1, 14.5, 16.2, 16.5, 16.9, 
    17.5, 17.6, 17.8, 19.9, 20.3, 20.4, 23.4, 21.5, 23.7, 23.9, 
    24.5, 26.2, 28.6, 34.2, 21.5, 23.1, 26.2, 29.4, 30.8, 24.9, 
    25.8, 26, 26, 26.3, 26.5, 27.1, 28, 30.5, 24.4, 26.2, 27, 
    28.2, 28.2, 29.2, 29.7, 21.8, 22.9, 23.8, 28.9, 20.8, 21.4, 
    23, 23.1, 23.1, 24, 26.3, 26.7, 27.4, 27.5, 14.9, 16.1, 16.8, 
    18.1, 19.1, 22.3, 23.1, 18.8, 19.5, 23.1, 25.6, 25.7)), row.names = c(NA, 
-813L), class = "data.frame")

Any comment appreciated, thanks!

Please don't modify the output of dput before pasting it into your post.
